# Add buttons to webpage with Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a Chrome Extension that will add a button on Deezer's album page.

My manifest is as follows:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Deezeet",
  "description": ".",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.deezer.com/*", "http://www.deezer.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js", "popup.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["script.js"],
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://api.deezer.com; object-src 'self' https://api.deezer.com; script-src 'self'"
}
```

My popup.js (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script)):

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL('script.js');
s.onload = function() {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
};
(document.head||document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

And my script.js (just for tests now):

```
$('header').hide();
```

But it doesn't work. All of my JS works inside the popup. What can I do?

Comment: Are you sure your jQuery selector is correct? Did you by any chance mean `'#header'` or `'.header'`? Also note that injected script won't be able to use jQuery you injected as a content script.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure ;-) I even add whole jQuery code in my `script.js`, but it didn't help. Like I said before, even if I use `alert('bam')` or something as simple, it all runs _inside_ my popup.

Comment: Why do you have a _popup_ in the first place? You have a content script defined, you should examine the page you're trying to inject into. Calling a popup does _nothing_ with other pages as it is.

Comment: Hm. I used popup before to maintain script, but now, it's propbly useless. I'll test it right away and tell you the results.

Comment: Removing `popup.html` helped, @Xan, please post this as an answer so I can accept it ;-)

Comment: No need to inject either. See the sample content scripts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're opening a popup and seeing the effects in the popup:

> [...] even if I use alert('bam') or something as simple, it all runs inside my popup.

When you open it, it has nothing to do with any other pages. You've set your script as a content script. It will execute when you navigate to a page or refresh an existing page.

---

If you need your script to fire when you click your extension button, you should remove the `default_popup` property from the manifest, add a background script and put into it a click handler:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab){
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "popup.js"});
  // Or, alternatively, send a message to an already-injected script
});
```

---

Please note: injecting a script as a `<script>` element is a very heavy-handed solution, needed only to escape isolated context. In your test case, you're only accessing the page's DOM, and your `popup.js` wrapper is not needed.